# Implementing "Starts with" and "Ends with" queries with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Am wondering if anyone can provide some guidance on how I might implement a starts with or ends with query against a Datastore model using Python?

In pseudo code, it would work something like...

Query for all entities A where property P starts with X

or

Query for all entities B where property P ends with X

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do a 'starts with' query by using inequality filters:

```
MyModel.all().filter('prop >=', prefix).filter('prop <', prefix + u'\ufffd')
```

Doing an 'ends with' query would require storing the reverse of the string, then applying the same tactic as above.

Comment: Thanks.  This worked in combination with storing the data in same case   (either lower or upper).  Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Matty, yet another case in which nonrelational DBs require denormalization (based on knowing the important queries) for efficiency.  Sigh, but, we'd better all get used to it!-)

Comment: Shouldn't this be ('prop <=', prefix + '\uffff') ?

Comment: @Isaac \ufffd is the highest numbered valid character in the unicode basic multilingual plane - \ufffe-\uffff are not valid characters.

Comment: @Isaac In the unlikely even you expect Unicode replacement characters in your string, <= wouldn't be sufficient either, since 'foo\ufffd\ufffd' is still greater than 'foo\ufffd'.

Comment: This syntax is also valid: `MyModel.query(MyModel.prop >= prefix, MyModel.prop < prefix + u'\ufffd')`

Comment: @Jeremy That's valid with ndb, but not with db, which this answer was originally written for.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you can't do it for the general case, but can do it for prefix searches (starts with):

[Wildcard search on Appengine in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402769/wildcard-search-on-appengine-in-python)