# How to match strings that contain a string using a filter - Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In Google App Engine, how do I match strings that contain strings? My datastore contains 'tester' and if I pass in 'est' then tester should be returned.

```
Filter myFilter =  new FilterPredicate("name",FilterOperator.IN, "est");
```

But I receive this error: `A collection of values is required`

I do not think I am using the filter correctly.

Comment: it seems cannot do a wildcard search on app engine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402769/wildcard-search-on-appengine-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an IN filter the way you described.  IN works if you give a list of strings, and want to match one of the strings in the given list.

The search API exists for what you're trying to do:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview

It's possible to find strings that start with a substring using a greater than/less than search, but you'll need to use the Search API if you want to find the substring anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this, even though app engine does not support wildcards is to insert every possible sequential combination to the datastore.

So if wanted to do a wildcard search on 'design'

Add the following entries :

```
'd'
'de'
'des'
'desi'
'desig'
'design'
'e'
'es'
'esi'
'esig'
'esign'
's'
'si'
'sig'
'sign'
'i'
'ig'
'ign'
'g'
'gn'
'n'
```

These are all possible combinations for a wildcard search on 'design'. Although this is very wasteful of data storage memory.

Answer (score 0):

Since strings can be compaired with >= and <= you could store the combinations:
design
esign
sign
ign
gn
n
To search for all names with 'sign' in them you would do a query for:

name >= 'sign' AND name <= 'sign\uffffd'

Practically you may get away with limiting the combination truncation to say 4 characters; few people are likely to need a full set of results for a search for all names with 'n' in.

Comment: What's \ufffd ?

Comment: @thegreatcoder just a very big unicode value. I was using java when I coded that query.